# Text button alignment issues

Tags: html, css

I hope you are well... I'm currently experiencing text alignment problems, I have been unable to fix it after a number of attempts and would very much appreciate it if someone could help me and potentailly show where I went wrong too... many thanks! [![enter image description here][1]][1]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Before
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJanh.png

How I would like the text to be in red.
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLJZJ.png

Here is the code below.

```css
 body {
        background-color: #d12502;
        margin: 0px;
        
      
      }

      html, body {
        max-width: 100%;
    }

      .button {
        display: block;
        outline: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-decoration: none;
        font: 14px "Arial";
        
        overflow:hidden ;
        border-radius: 6px;
        padding: .4em 1em .5em 1em;
        margin: 10px ;
        background: #d12502;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(0% 100% 90deg, #377ad0, #52a8e8);
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#52a8e8), to(#377ad0));
        border-top: 1px solid #4081af;
        border-right: 1px solid #2e69a3;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #20559a;
        border-left: 1px solid #2e69a3;
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 #72b9eb, 0 1px 2px 0 #b3b3b3;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 #72b9eb, 0 1px 2px 0 #b3b3b3;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 #72b9eb, 0 1px 2px 0 #b3b3b3;
        color: #fff;
        -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
      }

   

.arrow {
  border: solid #d12502;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding:3px;
  float: right;
  margin:-22px -260px ; 

}

.right {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}




.button {
    padding: .35em 20em 10vw 42vw;
    margin: -10px 3vw;
  text-align: left;

  height: 15px;
  width: 50vw;
    background: #ffffff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(0% 100% 90deg, #fcfdff, #ffffff);
 border: none;  
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.808);
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
}
 
.button:hover {
    background: #d12502;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(0% 100% 90deg, #d12502, #d12502);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#d12502), to(#d12502));
    border: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 #d12502;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 #d12502;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    </head>

    <style>
      #navbar {
          width: 125vw;
          height: 40px;
          margin: 0px;
          background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      }

      #navbar img {
          display: block;
          width: 200px;
          height: 40px;
          margin: auto;

      }

     p {
margin: 10px 10px 10px -110px;
white-space: normal;

     }

      img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}


      div {
  width: 25px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  margin: -7vw 108vw 8.3vw;
  
  


}





  </style>

<body>


  <nav id="navbar">
    <img src="logo.png" alt="Logo image">
    
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>

</nav>

<br>


<br>



<img src=".png" class=""><button class="button"><p>THIS IS BUTTON NUMBER ONE </p><i class="arrow right"></i></button>
<br>
<img src=".png" class=""><button class="button"><p>Success</p><i class="arrow right"></i></button>

<br>
<img src=".png" class=""><button class="button"><p>Success</p><i class="arrow right"></i></button>
<br>

<img src=".png" class=""><button class="button"><p>Success</p><i class="arrow right"></i></button>

<img src=" .jpeg" class="">
<br>
<br>
<img src=".png" class=""><button class="button"><p>Success</p><i class="arrow right"></i></button>
<br>
<img src=".png" class=""><button class="button"><p>Success</p><i class="arrow right"></i></button>
<br>
<img src=".png" class=""><button class="button"><p>Success</p><i class="arrow right"></i></button>


    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed some and you can see the new `.button-wrap` wrapper class. This class is needed to align the image and the button. If the image is not needed, then you can delete this class and everything will work as before.

HTML:

```
<style>
  #navbar {
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  }

  #navbar img {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: auto;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <nav id="navbar">
    <img src="logo.png" alt="Logo image">
  </nav>
  <div class="button-wrap">
    <img src=".png" class=""><button class="button">
      <p>THIS IS BUTTON NUMBER ONE </p><i class="arrow right"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="button-wrap">
    <img src=".png" class=""><button class="button">
      <p>Success</p><i class="arrow right"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="button-wrap">
    <img src=".png" class=""><button class="button">
      <p>Success</p><i class="arrow right"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="button-wrap">
    <img src=".png" class=""><button class="button">
      <p>Success</p><i class="arrow right"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="button-wrap">
    <img src=".png" class=""><button class="button">
      <p>Success</p><i class="arrow right"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="button-wrap">
    <img src=".png" class=""><button class="button">
      <p>Success</p><i class="arrow right"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="button-wrap">
    <img src=".png" class=""><button class="button">
      <p>Success</p><i class="arrow right"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</body>
```

I used flexbox to align text and arrow. Works well and everything looks great.

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: #d12502;
  margin: 0px;
}

html,
body {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.button-wrap {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.button {
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 60%;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: 14px "Arial";
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 0.4em 1em 0.5em 1em;
  margin: 10px;
  background: #d12502;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(0% 100% 90deg, #377ad0, #52a8e8);
  background: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    0% 0%,
    0% 100%,
    from(#52a8e8),
    to(#377ad0)
  );
  border-top: 1px solid #4081af;
  border-right: 1px solid #2e69a3;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #20559a;
  border-left: 1px solid #2e69a3;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 #72b9eb, 0 1px 2px 0 #b3b3b3;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 #72b9eb, 0 1px 2px 0 #b3b3b3;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 #72b9eb, 0 1px 2px 0 #b3b3b3;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
}
.arrow {
  border: solid #d12502;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
  float: right;
}

.right {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.button:hover {
  background: red;
  border: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 #d12502;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 #d12502;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

Comment: The text on the buttons still don't seem to be adjusting accordingly, would you be able to have another look for me... I'm just wanting the text to be in the same line instead of it being wrapped text causing small lines but words in a sentence to be underneath eachother. i have updated the code snippet

Comment: I changed my answer. U can check it

Answer (score 1):

Under `<style>` on the HTML doc.

```
  p {
margin: 10px 10px 10px -110px;
white-space: normal;

     }
```

That `white-space: normal;` change it to `white-space: nowrap;`
Tested on codepen, that should bring your text back to one line.

Click here for more Info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using paragraph tags inside **button** tags, why? [Visit here.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-button-element). That being said, you can use **span** tag inside the button element to achieve what you want and that's what I have done below. As you can see, I have also wrapped your icon inside span, so it stays vertically aligned upon floating to the right. I have also removed few properties to the `.arrow` class as you can see. You can give your own class to the span elements and replace it in styles also. I have given a custom width to the button element and you can change it to your need.

```css
.test-button {
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px;
}

.arrow {
  border: solid #d12502;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
}

.right {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.test-span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
}

.test-icon {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<button class="test-button">
  <span class="test-span">THIS IS BUTTON NUMBER ONE</span> <span class="test-icon"><i class="arrow    right"></i></span>
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining where I made the mistakes, it was very helpful! I have learnt from them! : )